# How to set the add to cart button to get the price from a form field?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am currently working on a ecommerce site. The word press theme I'm using is Astra. I have a form which calculate the prices for certain products. I want the add to cart button to get the final price from the form. How can I do that? Please help.

Comment: Hello and welcome to S.O. , please share the code you already have so we can reference it

Comment: if(isset($_POST['id_to_adjust']) && $_POST['id_to_adjust'] != ""){

        $id_to_adjust = $_POST['id_to_adjust'];
        $price = $_POST['post'];
 } But this code is not working. I am blank at the moment.